# Count clicks and store them at FTP

Tags: php, javascript, sql, text, counter

I already made a counter in JavaScript. Really basic... just increasing the value of an variable.

What I am looking for now is a way to store this on my FTP server. I want to count the clicks of a button. `onClick=""` And I also just want to show it in a  tag that gets the value of the text file.

The problem is that I have no idea how to code this and witch language I should use. I can use all web based languages.

Comment: You've said you dont know which language to use, the answer is whichever you are most comfortable with and your hoster supports. Is the FTP server also your webserver? Why ftp? What have you tried?

Comment: You want to write a text file over FTP using JavaScript? Please don't!

Comment: Search for "Ajax" to send the counter value to the server. Which serverside language you use is completely your choice, any will work.

Comment: If you can use all web-based languages, then there should be no problem choosing which one to use. In case you need to get a list of them to organiz your thoughts, you can find on:http://www.objs.com/survey/lang.htm

Comment: I posted a code example below based on the assumptions that with "at FTP" you mean "on my web server" and that you wouldn't mind using jQuery instead of onclick="".

Comment: Well... jQuery is not going to work :(

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function()
{
   $('#result').load("pathtophpfile.php");
});
```

And then create a PHP File that basically looks into the file and increments it's value:

```
    <?php

    $clicks = file_get_contents("clicks.txt");
    $clicks++;

    $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $clicks);
    fclose($fp);

    //debug
    echo "result: $clicks";

    ?>
```

Here's a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4QhL8/1/

Comment: Can I do this without jQuery?

Comment: You can, but jQuery makes the whole process much easier

Comment: Ok thank you. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/w1iJE68u

The php file is named count.php and lays in the same folder as the HTML file. I can't see what I have done wrong here.

Comment: @Sandeep I think I like your jQuery better than mine :-)

Comment: But there is something wrong in the code and I can't see it. pastebin.com/w1iJE68u

Comment: your result's div id is `results`, it needs to be `result`

Comment: I tried that too now, but no sucsess. I have no idea of what I am doing wrong here, but can you just paste it somewhere with the right code.

Comment: Look at my jsFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/4QhL8/1/ just as a note, .load uses relative files, so instead of `http://www.domain.com/clicks.txt` use `clicks.txt`

Comment: XMLreq without the jQuery. Saves space!

Answer (score 1):

you can make an ajax call to a server side php script which can store clicks in a text file. Then get contents of that text file in same script and send back the response to ajax script which should update the concerned element on HTML page.

P.S. : I am no supporter for php, it's just next to my natural language to me :)